# custom object with null type error in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to get an image of my API but not understanding, it is returning a null as an error, I can't fix it, can someone help me?

Log:

```
  private final com.example.pokedex.model.PokemonImage images = null;
                                                     ^
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

class PokemonIem:

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import androidx.room.TypeConverters
import com.example.pokedex.Converters
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import java.io.Serializable

@Entity(tableName = "PokemonItem")
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
data class PokemonItem(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: String = "",
    @SerializedName("name") val nome: String = "",
    val images: PokemonImage,
    val types: List<String>,
    val abilities: List<PokemonAbility>,
    val hp: String = ""

) : Serializable
```

data class PokemonImage

```
data class PokemonImage(
@SerializedName("small") val smallImageUrl: String
)
```

I tried to create a converter but it didn't work for my PokemonImage

Comment: Looks like the application is failing its build because of the following line: private final com.example.pokedex.model.PokemonImage images = null;
Could you share the code for the class where that line is written?

Comment: Yes, I will share as an answer. Clicking on the error calls the class PokemonIem.java

Answer (score 0):

class PokemonItem.java which is called by clicking on the error

```
private final com.example.pokedex.model.PokemonImage images = null;
@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```